# How can I import all export consts at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
export const getURLPath = (url) => url.split('.com')[1]
export const getSectionName = (path) => path.split('/butik/liste')[1]
export const getIdByName = (sectionName) => sectionMapping.find(item => item.name.toLowerCase() == sectionName).id
export const getNameById = (sectionId) => sectionMapping.find(item => item.id == sectionId).name.toLowerCase()
export const getContentIdFromURL = (path) => path.split('-p-').pop().split('?')[0];
export const getBoutiqueIdFromURL = (path) => path.split('boutiqueId=').pop().split('&')[0];
export const getMerchantIdFromURL = (path) => path.split('merchantId=').pop().split('&')[0];
```

I want to import all functions on the right. And i want to use with their pure name. For sample: getURLPath() just like this, not with prefix etc. How can i make this?

Comment: Don't post code as images, it's impossible to copy-paste and edit. Use code blocks instead.

Comment: Sorry, i edited this

Answer (score 0):

```js
 export default {
    getURLPath : (url) => url.split('.com')[1],
    getSectionName : (path) => path.split('/butik/liste')[1],
    getIdByName : (sectionName) => sectionMapping.find(item => item.name.toLowerCase() == sectionName).id,
    getNameById : (sectionId) => sectionMapping.find(item => item.id == sectionId).name.toLowerCase(),
    getContentIdFromURL : (path) => path.split('-p-').pop().split('?')[0],
    getBoutiqueIdFromURL : (path) => path.split('boutiqueId=').pop().split('&')[0],
    getMerchantIdFromURL : (path) => path.split('merchantId=').pop().split('&')[0],
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the `utils.getURLPath` syntax, then simply enough the only way is to spell all of them out, i.e.

```
import {getURLPath, getSectionName, getIdByName, getNameById, /* etc ... */} from '../utils';
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this:

```js
export const fun1...;
export const fun2...;
...

// This is not even mandatory I think but leaves u the choice to use prefix at some point. As u wish
export default {
  fun1,
  fun2,
}
```

And then import them in your other file like:

```js
import {
  fun1,
  fun2,
  ...
} from '/your/file';

// Then use them
fun1();
```